# Can I save page pictures directly from GreaseMonkey script

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, filesystem-access

Can I save page pictures from GreaseMonkey script directly to my hard drive?

Is the easiest way to do it - to setup my server and translate picture urls to it using **GM_xmlhttpRequest** ?

Comment: It's possible. Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36719491/2441026

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. GreaseMonkey still is within the Browser sandbox and this means you cannot access any system resources. There is no FileSystem API in (browser-integrated) JavaScript anyway.

Maybe [DownThemAll!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/201) helps you.